# System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported. windows server 2012

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, cng

I'm tiring to generate the jwt token for calling apns. here is my code:

```
    var header = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "kid" , keyID }
    };
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "iss", teamID },
        { "iat", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString() }
    };

    var privateKey = GetApnsPrivateKey(authKeyPath);
    var token = JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, header);
public static CngKey GetApnsPrivateKey(string authKeyPath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(authKeyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
    {
        var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
        var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
        var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
        var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        return EccKey.New(x, y, d);
```

code works on my machine just fine but in the server it throw this exception on `GetApnsPrivateKey` method:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The requested operation is not supported
```

after little search on the forums i found out its because of CNG Key Storage Providers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376242.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
now i wonder is there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: `EccKey.New` isn't a NetFx method, so where did it come from / what is its implementation?

Comment: hello dear @bartonjs. EccKey.New is the Cryptography library method. here is the method full path: Security.Cryptography.EccKey.New(x, y, d);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the exception is System.Security.Cryptography library inside the jose-jwt, so avoid it. 
Since BouncyCastle library is already in use here, use it for signing.
Also, I use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert(..).

```
public string GetApnsToken(string authKeyPath,  
Dictionary<string, object> payload, 
Dictionary<string, object> header)
{
    ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParameters;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(new FileStream(authKeyPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)))
    {
       ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
     }
     byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header));
     byte[] payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload));
     byte[] bytesToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConcatTokenPartsWithEncoding(headerBytes, payloadBytes));

   var signer = new DsaDigestSigner(new ECDsaSigner(), new Sha256Digest());
   signer.Init(true, ecPrivateKeyParameters);
   signer.BlockUpdate(bytesToSign, 0, bytesToSign.Length);
   byte[] signBytes = signer.GenerateSignature();

   return ConcatTokenPartsWithEncoding(headerBytes, payloadBytes, signBytes);

}

public static string ConcatTokenPartsWithEncoding(params byte[][] parts)
{
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var part in parts)
{
 //encode base64 for Url
 var base64Str = Convert.ToBase64String(part);
 base64Str = base64Str.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
 base64Str = base64Str.Replace('+', '-'); 
 base64Str = base64Str.Replace('/', '_');
 builder.Append(base64Str).Append(".");
}
builder.Remove(builder.Length - 1, 1); 
return builder.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Natalya's post. i could solve the problem like this:

```
        var dateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var privateKeyAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authKey);
        var privateKey = CngKey.Import(privateKeyAsBytes, CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
        var header = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "kid", keyID } };
        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "iss", teamID }, { "iat", dateTime.ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString() } };
        var token = JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.ES256, header);
```

Comment: Hi what is the authKey in this example? I have same code as you had but not sure how to change to what you shown here